# Prevent multiple SQL querys with model relations

Tags: django

Is it possible to prevent multiple querys when i use django ORM ? Example:

```
product = Product.objects.get(name="Banana")
for provider in product.providers.all():
    print provider.name
```

This code will make 2 SQL querys:

> 1 - SELECT ••• FROM stock_product WHERE stock_product.name = 'Banana'
>
> 2 - SELECT stock_provider.id, stock_provider.name FROM stock_provider INNER JOIN stock_product_reference ON (stock_provider.id = stock_product_reference.provider_id) WHERE stock_product_reference.product_id = 1

I confess, i use [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) (PHP) for some projects. With doctrine it's possible to specify **joins** when retrieve the object (relations are populated in object, so no need to query database again for get attribute relation value).

Is it possible to do the same with Django's ORM ?

PS: *I hop my question is comprehensive, english is not my primary language.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django 1.4 or later, you can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). It's like `select_related` but allows M2M relations and such.

```
product = Product.objects.prefetch_related('providers').get(name="Banana")
```

You still get two queries, though. From the docs:

> prefetch_related, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python.

As for packing this down into a single query, Django won't do it like Doctrine because it doesn't do that much post-processing of the result set (Django would have to remove all the redundant column data, since you'll get a row per provider and each of these rows will have a copy of all of `product`'s fields).

So if you want to pack this down to one query, you're going to have to turn it around and run the query on the `Provider` table (I'm guessing at your schema):

```
providers = Provider.objects.filter(product__name="Banana").select_related('product')
```

This should pack it down to one query, *but* you won't get a single `product` ORM object out of it, instead needing to get the product fields via `providers[k].product`.

Comment: Okay, so i have to use a different approach between Doctrine and Django ORM. Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prefetch_related`, sometimes in combination with `select_related`, to get all related objects in a single query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: A single line of Python, but not a single query.

Comment: Right, it depends on how the relationships are structured and from which direction you run your query.